# Permission denied while trying to access files in container during docker-compose(UBUNTU 20.04)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, rasa

I am trying to work on a project which involves using rasa, when I run `sudo docker-compose up` , I get the following error .

```
Starting ask-my-doctor_rasa_1  ... done
Attaching to ask-my-doctor_ngrok_1, ask-my-doctor_rasa_1
rasa_1   | bash: line 15: /app/credentials.yml: Permission denied
rasa_1   | bash: line 16: /app/train_logs.txt: Permission denied
rasa_1   | bash: line 17: /app/run_actions_logs.txt: Permission denied
rasa_1   | 2021-06-07 14:02:52 DEBUG    rasa.telemetry  - Could not read telemetry settings from configuration file: Configuration 'metrics' key not found.
rasa_1   | 2021-06-07 14:02:52 WARNING  rasa.utils.common  - Failed to write global config. Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.config'. Skipping.
rasa_1   | 2021-06-07 14:02:53 DEBUG    rasa.cli.run  - 'models' not found. Using default location 'models' instead.
rasa_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
rasa_1   |   File "/opt/venv/bin/rasa", line 8, in <module>
rasa_1   |     sys.exit(main())
rasa_1   |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/__main__.py", line 117, in main
rasa_1   |     cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
rasa_1   |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/run.py", line 118, in run
rasa_1   |     args.model = _validate_model_path(args.model, "model", DEFAULT_MODELS_PATH)
rasa_1   |   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/run.py", line 71, in _validate_model_path
rasa_1   |     os.makedirs(default, exist_ok=True)
rasa_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
rasa_1   |     mkdir(name, mode)
rasa_1   | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'models'
ask-my-doctor_rasa_1 exited with code 1
```

I have also tried to just keep the container running and tried to login and create a file just to check and there as well I get the "permission denied" message.

How do I solve this permission issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, post you docker-compose file and dockerfile.

Comment: The error also needs to be included directly in the question (not behind a link) and as text (not an image).

Comment: Sure @DavidMaze will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the docker-compose method to run Rasa, several folders will be mounted into the containers.

I suspect that the group and permissions of the mounted directories are not correct.

Can you please try this:

```sh
# Go to root folder of your deployment folder.
# Default is /etc/rasa, but from your error image, I see it is different.
cd ~/Project/ask-my-doctor

# Set group & permissions for everything in that folder
sudo chgrp -R root * && sudo chmod -R 770 *

# Correct group & permissions for the database
sudo chown -R 1001 db && sudo chmod -R 750 /db
```

---

A detailed explanation of these steps can be found in the [rasa docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/docker-compose/#mounted-directories), for Linux/macOS users:

The Rasa containers are following Docker’s best practices and are not running as `root` user. Hence, please make sure that the `root` group has read and write access to the following directories and their content:

- /etc/rasa/credentials.yml
- /etc/rasa/endpoints.yml
- /etc/rasa/environments.yml
- /etc/rasa/auth
- /etc/rasa/certs
- /etc/rasa/credentials
- /etc/rasa/models
- /etc/rasa/logs

To set the permissions and group for everything in `/etc/rasa` you can use this command, but make sure to correct it for the `/etc/rasa/db` directory as described in the next step:

```sh
sudo chgrp -R root /etc/rasa/* && sudo chmod -R 770 /etc/rasa/*
```

If you are mounting different or extra directories, please adapt their permissions accordingly.

**Postgres Database Storage**
Configure persistent Postgres database storage

On Linux, a local directory is used for persistent Postgres database storage.
You must set the correct owner and permissions of the database persistence directory using this command:

```sh
sudo chown -R 1001 /etc/rasa/db && sudo chmod -R 750 /etc/rasa/db
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I could not figure out how to give the necessary permissions.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nikhilv.h.  Can you mark it as the accepted answer?  Great question btw.